# C++ Changing elements of an array using only pointers

Tags: c++

I'm working on a problem where I cannot use array indexing to change elements and I'm really struggling with pointers. This is code is supposed to initialize an array with all index initialized to 0, except for indexes 0 and 1. Indexes 0 and 1 are initialized to -1. The array I get back has weird numbers in it,

```
int* arr(int size);
int main()
{
    int low, high;
    char again = 'y';
    high = low = 0;

    cout << "\tThe Sieve of Eratosthenes" << endl << endl;
    do
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "Enter the high boundary: ";
            cin >> high;
            cout << endl;
            if (high <= 0)
                cout << "ERROR: HIGH BOUNDARY MUST BE POSITIVE" << endl;
        } while (high < 0);

        int* thearr = arr(high);
        cout << "The prime numbers from to " << high << " are: " << endl;

        for (int ix = 0; ix <= high; ++ix)
        {
            cout << thearr[ix] << "  ";
        }

        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "Try again with new boundaries? (y/n):" << endl;
        cin >> again;

        delete[] thearr;

    } while (again == 'y');

    return 0;
}

int* arr(int size)
{
    int* thearray = new int[size];
    int last = size;
    cout << *thearray << " " << last;
    while (*thearray < last)
    {
        if (*thearray <= 1)
            thearray[*thearray] = 0;
        else
            thearray[*thearray] = -1;
        ++thearray;
        cout << *thearray;
    }
    return thearray;
}
```

Comment: When you allocate memory with `new[]`, the memory will be *uninitialized* and have *indeterminate* contents. That makes the conditions in your `arr` function invalid and have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Furthermore (also in the function `arr`) when the loop ends, then `thearray` will no longer point to the original location that `new[]` returned. The pointer you return will be invalid.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: arr is supposed to return an initialized array and I dont know how to do that without new[]

Comment: First of all, `*thearray` is *exactly* equal to `thearray[0]`. Secondly, if the value of `thearray[0]` is indeterminate (and could be seen as random or garbage), then how could you use that value in a condition (like e.g. `*thearray < last`)? You can initialize the array, that's not a problem ([`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) or [`std::fill_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) are very helpful here) but you can't use the contents before that initialization.

Comment: And `new[]` only ***allocates*** memory for you, it doesn't initialize the memory in any way.

Comment: `int* thearray = new int[size]();` <== note added parenthesis.

Comment: I still cannot traverse through the array to set the elements to 0

Comment: In the code fragments `while (*thearray < last)`, `if (*thearray <= 1)`, and `thearray[*thearray]` it looks like you believe the value of `*thearray` is the array index. It's not, it's the value that the pointer is pointing to. All of that code is incorrect and doesn't do what you want. In addition when you do `++thearray;` you are incrementing the pointer (changing the address it contains). The address you eventually return is no longer the address you got from `new`.

Comment: What do I use for the index? This assignment does not allow me to use array indexing so I cannot just use a ix loop.

Comment: Note that if you call `arr(high)` then the loop `for (int ix = 0; ix <= high; ++ix)` will go out of bounds. You need to call `arr(high + 1)` (or use `ix < high` as loop condition).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to initialize your array to all zeros:

- Use value initialization

  ```
  int* thearray = new int[size]();
  ```
- Use [`std::fill_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n)

  ```
  int* thearray = new int[size];
  std::fill_n(thearray, size, 0);
  ```
- Use [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)

  ```
  int* thearray = new int[size];
  int* end = thearray + size;
  std::fill(thearray, end, 0);
  ```
- Use pointers and explicit loops

  ```
  int* thearray = new int[size];
  int* end = thearray + size;
  int* begin = thearray;

  while (begin < end)
  {
      *begin++ = 0;
  }

  // After loop thearray still points to the beginning of the array
  ```
- Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead

  ```
  std::vector<int> thearray(size);
  ```

If you *must* use raw pointers (due to the assignment or exercise conditions) then one of the first two is what I recommend.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1 - just use `std::vector`

The simple way to do this is to use `std::vector`, because `std::vector` makes life easy. You don't have to delete it, and it keeps track of it's length (call `.size()` to get the number of elements).

We can write `arr` pretty simply now:

```
std::vector<int> arr(int size) {
    std::vector<int> vect(size); // Everything initialized to 0
    vect[0] = -1;
    vect[1] = -1;
    return vect; 
}
```

#### Solution 2 - default-initialize the array

Write now, you have

```
int* thearray = new int[size];
```

This leaves the memory uninitialized. We can initialize it to 0 just by adding a `()` after `new int[size]`:

```
int* thearray = new int[size](); // array initialized to 0
```

We can rewrite `arr` like this:

```
int* arr(int size) {
    int* thearray = new int[size]();
    thearray[0] = -1;
    thearray[1] = -1;
    return thearray;
}
```

#### Solution 3 - use pointers on an uninitialized array.

Ok ok. So maybe you're into pointers, or maybe you're a student and your professor is evil. We can use them.

```
int* arr(int size) {
    int* vals = new int[size]; // Create the array
    // We need to return the ORIGINAL pointer (which is vals)
    // because we need to return the original pointer, we're gonna use a 
    // a new pointer called 'scan' to modify the array
    int* scan = vals; 
    *scan = -1; // Set the value at scan to -1 (this is vals[0])
    scan += 1;  // move scan to the next value in the array
    *scan = -1; // Do it again for vals[1]
    scan += 1;

    // Set the rest of the values to 0
    for(int i = 2; i < size; i++) {
        *scan = 0; // set the value to 0
        scan += 1; // move to the next value
    }

    return vals; // Return the ORIGINAL pointer
}
```