# Modifying Array Elements Using Pointers

Tags: c++

I'm working on a program that modifies the data of an array using only pointers. I'm trying to return the index where array[ix]==0. However, I keep getting stuck in an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
int firstprime(int size, int arr[]){
  int* end = arr + size;
  int* begin = arr;
    while(begin<end){
        if(*begin==0)
            return *begin;
        begin++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] reproducing your problem as required here please.

Comment: The code you show doesn't by itself have any problem. What are the arguments you pass to the function? How do you call it? As mentioned, please create a [mcve] (that replicates the problem) and show it to us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The code posted does not return the index. It returns the value. I think that's what the OP is having trouble with.

Comment: @Tayl Like your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55916355/c-changing-elements-of-an-array-using-only-pointers) you *still* seem to believe that the dereference operator gives you the index. It does not. As I said in a comment to that question, `*begin` is *exactly* equal to `begin[0]`. The dereference operator (unary `*`) gives you the value where the pointer is pointing, nothing else.

Comment: As for the infinite loop you claim you have, it's not in the function you show, ans should be posted as a separate question. Though if I should guess it's because with the code you show you return the value `0`, and if you use that returned value as part of a loop condition it will lead to problems, including possible infinite loops.

Comment: "However, I keep getting stuck in an infinite loop."  there is no infinite loop in your code, though what is missing from the question is a "How to return the index instead of the value?" It took me a while to understand what is the problem in the code, or what questions the answers actually adress

Comment: btw you are also not modifying array elements using pointers. May I suggest you to change the title to: "How to get the index, given a pointer to an array element?"

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::distance` quite easily to get the index.
More info on `std::distance` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

Btw, the function name is also very misleading. If the function is meant to return the index of a value in the array, then consider changing that function name, like `getIndex()` or `find()`. Just pick something more meaningful.

```
#include <iostream>

int firstprime(int size, int *arr)
{
    int *begin = arr;
    int *end = begin + size;
    while( begin < end )
    {
        if(*begin==0)
            return std::distance(arr, begin);
        begin++;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int array[10] = {1,2,3,4,0,6,7,8,9,10};
    int p = firstprime(10, array);
    std::cout<< "0 found at index: " << p <<std::endl;
}
```

The result is:

```
0 found at index: 4
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/KVCL75042

Comment: Though that answer doesn't explain why the OP's code is (seemingly) stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I don't think it did tbh. Unless his `end` pointer pointed before the `begin` pointer.

Comment: Why not simply `return std::distance(array, begin)`?

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos We probably have to wait until the OP provides a [mcve], before there can be wrtiiten a concise and solid answer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yep! That's even simpler. I'll modify.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It just seemed like a simple question and I kind of figured where the OP got stuck when I saw the return statement. `return *begin;` does not give you the index. I agree that he needed a simpl example to illustrate that infinite `while-loop`...

Answer (score 1):

To get the "distance" between two pointers (in the number of elements) you can either use [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance):

```
return std::distance(arr, begin);  // Return the distance between current element and the beginning of the array
```

You can also subtract the pointers:

```
return begin - arr;  // Return the distance between the current element and the beginning of the array
```

The "distance" returned by the above two statements will be in the number of elements, and since you take the distance from the first element it will be the index of the "current" element.

Comment: Using `begin - arr` is even simpler that using `std::distance`. +1